# When for every module $M$, $|E(M)| = |M|$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Is there a non-semisimple ring $R$ such that for any left $R$-module $M$, $|E(M)| = |M|$ ? (where $E(M)$ is the injective hull of $M$ and $|M|$ is the cardinality of $M$)

Answer (score 5):

If $R$ is a finite-dimensional algebra (of dimension $d$, say) over a field $k$, and $M$ is a left $R$-module, then
$$\dim(M)\leq\dim\left(E(M)\right)\leq d.\dim(M),$$
and so if $k$ is infinite then $|E(M)|=|M|$.